# Umbraco.config file is not being written/published

Tags: umbraco

Our Umbraco site was writing out its site structure to its XML config file for most of the project but recently it has stopped doing this and we don't know why. We haven't done anything new or unusual and we didn't notice it straight away so we are not to sure if there was a change that actually triggered this.

I have checked the premissions on the folder and i am sure that it has premissions to write.

I don't know what else to look for. Does anybody have any suggestions for what i should be looking for or experience with this happening?

Comment: I would start looking at IIS/Windows Server logs. I take you tried to replicate this issue locally on identical environment? If not then do this with and use tools like Visual Studio to debug (if poss.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well i figured it out after binary sorting my way through the revision history there was a change in the app config:

```
<add key="umbracoContentXMLUseLocalTemp" value="true" />
```

setting this to false made this reappear im my App_Data folder. I assume that it was actually appearing in the temp folder when this was set to true. If somebody wants to edit this answer with more specifics it would be interesting to know what this setting actually does.

Comment: See [here for a brief explanation](http://www.cupfighter.net/index.php/2011/03/umbraco-config-access-issues/). Essentially, setting this value to true will allow the umbraco.config to be generated in a specified, central location.

Answer (score 3):

The best place to start look at this problem is Umbraco Database.you can see a table name dbo.umbracoLog .In this table all activities like writing to xml config files will be recorded.If an error has occurred you will definitely get some info from there which will lead you to finding out the real cause